# Multiple users updating an access table at the same time

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have created a data entry application that works like this. All data entered goes in to an ACCESS table.  At any time the user can hit the update button and the new data in the ACCESS table updates a table in a SQL Server data base. Recently, we have a need for multiple people to be doing data entry at the same time, and I am a bit confused about what is happening with the ACCESS table.  I conducted experiments with two users updating the access table then closing the app before updating and after updating.  My question is this: everything seems to work fine, no data is missing from either the ACCESS table or the SQL Server table. This begs the question of where does the ACCESS table reside when two versions of the app are open at the same time.  Are there two versions of the ACCESS table or just one version that is used by both applications. I think it's the latter but I am not sure, because when we hit the update button on one users pc the data from both users is updated.  I am trying to decide if I need to put the ACCES table up on SQL SERVER as well but would like to avoid the extra work.

Thanks

JPL

Comment: My question is why are you storing the data in both Access and SQL Server? Access is not a good solution for any application with more than 1 user. I would suggest you store all your data on sql server and forget about storing it in access.

Comment: I designed and managed a multi-user split db with Access as frontend and  backend and has been running just fine for 10 years now. Each user runs their own copy of the frontend. I also built a non-split db (very simple, no macros or VBA) with multiple users and each user opens the same file and yes, surprisingly the data is saved in spite of all warnings against this. But I gave them what they asked for. However, I also question the need for intermediate Access table and not just connecting to the SQLServer file.

Comment: Thanks.  I understand your question regarding the design, but that's not going to change.  I just wanted to know how access works with multiple users going after the same access file that is part of the application. In my research it seems to work, just wanted to know why.